# Conditionally setting values with df.loc inside a loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I'm querying an MS Access db to retrieve a set of leases. My task is to calculate monthly totals for base rent for the next 60 months. The leases have dates related to start and end in order to calculate the correct periods in the event a lease terminates prior to 60 periods. My current challenge comes in when I attempt to increase the base rent by a certain amount whenever it's time to increment for that specific lease. I'm at a beginner level with Python/pandas so my approach is likely not optimum and the code rough looking. It's likely a vectorized approach is better suited however i'm not quite able to execute such code yet.

Data:
[Lease input & output](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/n4qyp2ei0k06jhb/AAAMupzLcdOSqjs6hjIF6VKma?dl=0)

Code:

```
try:
    sql = 'SELECT * FROM [tbl_Leases]'
    #sql = 'SELECT * FROM [Copy Of tbl_Leases]'
    df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)
    #print df
    #df.to_csv('lease_output.csv', index_label='IndexNo')

    df_fcst_periods = pd.DataFrame()

    # init increments
    periods = 0
    i = 0

    # create empty lists to store looped info from original df
    fcst_months = []
    fcst_lease_num = []
    fcst_base_rent = []
    fcst_method = []
    fcst_payment_int = []
    fcst_rate_inc_amt = []
    fcst_rate_inc_int = []
    fcst_rent_start =  []

    # create array for period deltas, rent interval calc, pmt interval calc
    fcst_period_delta =  []
    fcst_rate_int_bool = []
    fcst_pmt_int_bool = []

    for row in df.itertuples():

        # get min of forecast period or lease ending date
        min_period = min(fcst_periods, df.Lease_End_Date[i])

        # count periods to loop for future periods in new df_fcst
        periods =  (min_period.year - currentMonth.year) * 12 + (min_period.month - currentMonth.month)

        for period in range(periods):

            nextMonth = (currentMonth + monthdelta(period))
            period_delta = (nextMonth.year - df.Rent_Start_Date[i].year) * 12 + (nextMonth.month - df.Rent_Start_Date[i].month)
            period_delta = float(period_delta)

            # period delta values allow us to divide by the payment & rent intervals looking for integers
            rate_int_calc = period_delta/df['Rate_Increase_Interval'][i]
            pmt_int_calc = period_delta/df['Payment_Interval'][i]

            # float.is_integer() method - returns bool
            rate_int_bool = rate_int_calc.is_integer()
            pmt_int_bool = pmt_int_calc.is_integer()

            # conditional logic to handle base rent increases
            if df['Forecast_Method'][i] == "Percentage" and rate_int_bool:
                rate_increase = df['Base_Rent'][i] * (1 + df['Rate_Increase_Amt'][i]/100)
                df.loc[df.index, "Base_Rent"] = rate_increase
                fcst_base_rent.append(df['Base_Rent'][i])
                print "Both True"
            else:
                fcst_base_rent.append(df['Base_Rent'][i])
                print rate_int_bool

            fcst_rate_int_bool.append(rate_int_bool)
            fcst_pmt_int_bool.append(pmt_int_bool)
            fcst_months.append(nextMonth)
            fcst_period_delta.append(period_delta)
            fcst_rent_start.append(df['Rent_Start_Date'][i])
            fcst_lease_num.append(df['Lease_Number'][i])
            #fcst_base_rent.append(df['Base_Rent'][i])
            fcst_method.append(df['Forecast_Method'][i])
            fcst_payment_int.append(df['Payment_Interval'][i])
            fcst_rate_inc_amt.append(df['Rate_Increase_Amt'][i])
            fcst_rate_inc_int.append(df['Rate_Increase_Interval'][i])

        i += 1

    df_fcst_periods['Month'] = fcst_months
    df_fcst_periods['Rent_Start_Date'] = fcst_rent_start    
    df_fcst_periods['Lease_Number'] = fcst_lease_num
    df_fcst_periods['Base_Rent'] = fcst_base_rent
    df_fcst_periods['Forecast_Method'] = fcst_method
    df_fcst_periods['Payment_Interval'] = fcst_payment_int
    df_fcst_periods['Rate_Increase_Amt'] = fcst_rate_inc_amt
    df_fcst_periods['Rate_Increase_Interval'] = fcst_rate_inc_int
    df_fcst_periods['Period_Delta'] = fcst_period_delta
    df_fcst_periods['Rate_Increase_Interval_bool'] = fcst_rate_int_bool
    df_fcst_periods['Payment_Interval_bool'] = fcst_pmt_int_bool

except Exception, e:
    print str(e)
    conn.close()
```

Comment: This is way too long for what is probably an easy question you can answer by reading pandas docs. Start with docs on `ix/iloc/loc`. Don't do a loop here (or in general), simply use `loc` by itself. e.g. `df.loc[ df['Month'] == whatever, : ]`.  The loop is generally implicit with pandas (aka vectorized).

Comment: @JohnE thanks for the guidance. I'll check it out in more detail

Answer (score 0):

I ended up initializing a variable before the periods loop which allowed me to perform a calculation when looping to obtain the correct base rents for subsequent periods.

```
    # init base rent, rate increase amount, new rate for leases
    base_rent = df['Base_Rent'][i]
    rate_inc_amt = float(df['Rate_Increase_Amt'][i])
    new_rate = 0

    for period in range(periods):

        nextMonth = (currentMonth + monthdelta(period))
        period_delta = (nextMonth.year - df.Rent_Start_Date[i].year) * 12 + (nextMonth.month - df.Rent_Start_Date[i].month)
        period_delta = float(period_delta)

        # period delta values allow us to divide by the payment & rent intervals looking for integers
        rate_int_calc = period_delta/df['Rate_Increase_Interval'][i]
        pmt_int_calc = period_delta/df['Payment_Interval'][i]

        # float.is_integer() method - returns bool
        rate_int_bool = rate_int_calc.is_integer()
        pmt_int_bool = pmt_int_calc.is_integer()

        # conditional logic to handle base rent increases
        if df['Forecast_Method'][i] == "Percentage" and rate_int_bool:
            new_rate = base_rent * (1 + rate_inc_amt/100)
            base_rent = new_rate
            fcst_base_rent.append(new_rate)

        elif df['Forecast_Method'][i] == "Manual" and rate_int_bool:
            new_rate = base_rent + rate_inc_amt
            base_rent = new_rate
            fcst_base_rent.append(new_rate)

        else:
            fcst_base_rent.append(base_rent)
```

Still open for any alternative approaches though!